# how to echo value without backslash inside with json_encode

Tags: php, json

when i want to echo data from json with a `/` in it, it puts a backslash for the `/`.

How to remove the backslash?

This:

```
$data = [
"actualdir" => "uploads/aaa"
];
echo json_encode($data);
```

gives me this as output:

```
{"actualdir":"uploads\/aaa"}
```

And it should be:

```
{"actualdir":"uploads/aaa"}
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option for `json_encode` - viz:

```
echo json_encode( $data,  JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES );
```

Many other additional options are available - read more at [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)